# Junit is failed due to java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: junit, slf4j, aem-6

I have updated my uber jar from 6.2.0-SP1 to 6.4.0. After that all my Junit is failing with the following error.

If i remove the logger from the class then issue is not coming. Junit is working.

> Error message 1:  java.lang.StackOverflowError: null  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:936)
>     at
>   org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:39
>
> Error message 2: java.lang.StackOverflowError: null   at
>   org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:39)
>     at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:45)

Full Log trace :

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:357)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:57)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:37)
    at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:43)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:45)
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:64)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:358)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:57)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:37)
    at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:43)
```

Comment: I don't think there's really enough detail here for anyone to help you.  Do you have a complete stack trace?  What does your JUnit test look like?

Comment: @RobMcDougall: I have added stack trace log. I found in uber 6.4 jar has org.apache.log4j and  org.slf4j.log4j.* package but those package is not available in uber6.2 which has added separate dependency slf4j-api. I have removed "slf4j-api" dependency when i am using uber 6.4 but still same issue.

Answer (score 0):

With the rare information you gave us, I would guess you have not set up the logger correctly anymore due to the update you made(perhaps the newer version requires some more configuration).
(Would like to post this as a comment, but my reputation is too low, sry :) )

Because of the improve info you gave, it really looks like you have no logger intialized. Maybe the getLogger-Method tries to find a logger recursive which causes the StackOverflowError.

Comment: Added more info

Comment: There is no other info i have on this issue. just updated uber jar version and it creates this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue by excluding the slf4j-log4j12 from the bundle which is referred in one of the custom jar. Now there is no cyclic call between slf4j-api and slf4j-log4j12.